# Sub enumeration rawValue

Tags: swift, enums

Consider the following code, where I declared an `enum` with sub enums inside of it.

```
enum LocalizeKey {
case message(Messages)
case buttons(Buttons)
enum Buttons: String {
    case remove = "Remove"
    case add = "Add"
}
enum Messages: String {
    case success = "Success"
    case failure = "Failure"
 }
}
```

In a normal `enum` with no sub enums we can easily access `.rawValue` property and get the raw value of whatever case we picked.

For this case, i created a function like this just to check out what am i getting .

```
func keyString(for type: LocalizeKey) {
    print(type)
 }
keyString(for: .message(.failure)) // usage
```

**Problem** : there are no other properties than `.self` to access for this `LocalizeKey` enum .

**What I am trying to achieve:**   perhaps you can relate by the naming, i am trying to wrap my localized keys, so i can access them easily based on the key type etc, and the `rawValue` that is refering to the actual key will go into the `getLocalizedValue` function .

**Playground Output** : using the function above the playground output was

> message(__lldb_expr_21.LocalizeKey.Messages.failure)

**Edit:**  without having to create a variable that switches self on every case, imagine if we had +400 key that would be a huge mess probably.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to be able to access the raw string values of `Buttons` and `Messages` in the `keyString` function?

Comment: yes because the `LocalizeKey` lets call it the base enum holds the types of keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `switch` on the `type` parameter and do pattern matching:

```
switch type {
    case .message(let messages): return messages.rawValue
    case .buttons(let buttons): return buttons.rawValue
}
```

You can also make this an extension of `LocalizeKey`:

```
extension LocalizeKey {
    var keyString: String {
        switch self {
            case .message(let messages): return messages.rawValue
            case .buttons(let buttons): return buttons.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MohmmadS wvteijlingen mentioned a code generation tool in his answer, so I don't think it will be a problem to write such a method and there won't be any typos. As for readability, most people get what you are doing after reading the first few cases.

Comment: it took me couple of seconds to click, :D thanks for the insight i was really close to this implementation but i wanted to see what others would recommend, appreciate your answer mate .

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to switch somewhere. If there are only a handful of "sub-enums", it is probably the easiest to just write a switch manually:

```
func keyString(for type: LocalizeKey) {
  switch type {
  case .message(let message):
    print(message.rawValue)
  case .buttons(let button):
    print(button.rawValue)
  }
}
```

If you don't want to write this manually, you either have to change your data structure so it is not needed, or use a [code generation tool](https://nshipster.com/swift-gyb/) that generates the boilerplate for you.

Comment: So it is a must after all to switch, however regarding the technical problem of the enum, could you suggest a different or more efficient approach  to achieve  what i am trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Although The mentioned answers do provide the solution, I'd mention the issue of the approach itself:

At this point, each new case (key) has to be added in your `switch` statement with an associated value, which seems to be undesired boilerplate coding; I assume that you could imagine how it will look like when having *many* cases in the enums.

Therefore, I'd recommend to follow an approach to be more dynamic instead of adding the value of each case manually in a `switch` statement. Example:

```
protocol Localizable {
    var value: String { get }
}

extension RawRepresentable where Self: Localizable, Self.RawValue == String {
    var value: String { return rawValue }
}

extension CustomStringConvertible where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    var description: String { return rawValue }
}

struct LocalizeKey {

    enum Buttons: String, Localizable, CustomStringConvertible {
        case remove = "Remove"
        case add = "Add"
    }

    enum Messages: String, Localizable, CustomStringConvertible {
        case success = "Success"
        case failure = "Failure"
    }
}
```

We are applying the same logic for your code, with some improvements to make it easier to maintain.

Based on that, you still able to implement your function as:

```
func keyString(for type: Localizable) {
    print(type)
}
```

Usage:

```
keyString(for: LocalizeKey.Buttons.add) // Add
keyString(for: LocalizeKey.Messages.success) // Success
```

IMO, I find calling it this way seems to be more readable, straightforward rather than the proposed approach (`keyString(for: .message(.failure))`).